# Linear Algebra: Eigenvalues of matrix multiplied with transpose.

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition, svd

In SVD, the orthogonal matrices $U$ and $V^T$ have same nonzero eigenvalues in their complete set of eigenvalues. What might the proof of this statement?

The cited document is - [here](https://www.ling.ohio-state.edu/~kbaker/pubs/Singular_Value_Decomposition_Tutorial.pdf). On page 20.

Comment: Do you mean the same *number* of non-zero eigenvalues? As in, they'll have the same *rank*?

Comment: What I understood from that document is that, he wrote that the values of eigenvalues that are non zero in both the sets will be equal. For example a1=10,a2=12 and b1=0,b2=10,b3=12.

Comment: He's talking about the non-zero eigenvalues of $U$ and $V$, not $A$ and $A^TA$.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the text. Edited the question.

Comment: It seems I misunderstood the text my self: he means that $AA^T$ (used to construct $U$) and $A^TA$ (used to construct $V$) have the same non-zero eigenvalues.  This is a well-known result... there should be another post on this site with the proof.

Comment: In fact, for any two matrices with the correct dimensions, $AB$ and $BA$ have the same non-zero eigenvalues.

Comment: It's certainly **not** true that $U$ and $V^T$ have the same eigenvalues (you don't have to say nonzero, because orthogonal matrices are invertible by definition).  $U$ and $V^T$ can be any orthogonal matrices of the correct dimensions.

Comment: I guess that justifies the "ROUGH DRAFT - BEWARE" in the cited link.